# Meaning of short, medium and long baselines

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, oscillators, neutrinos

I was reading about the experiments on Neutrinos and came accross terms like "Short", "long" and "medium" baseline experiments. Can anyone please tell me how do we define these terms? Like the distance and how can it affect the neutrino oscillations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the [pdg](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/reviews/rpp2022-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf) neutrino oscillation formula (14.40), crudely
$$
\sin^2 \left(1.267~\frac{\Delta m^2}{\mathrm{eV}^2}~\frac{L/E}{\mathrm{km/GeV}}\right ).
$$
The point is to monitor oscillations against *L*, to measure the
crucial mass-difference-squared among the mass eigenstates involved in the lepton-flavor mixing.

- A ***short baseline*** is an *L/E* only sensitive to *large*  $\Delta m^2$s in the stated units, so you may only probe such with variations of *L* for a given *E*, such that the product in the trigonometric argument can vary over a few cycles. That is, you can see oscillations if  ${\Delta m^2} {L/E}$ goes through a few π cycles with varying *L*.

But if $\Delta m^2$ is sufficiently *small*, e.g. <$10^{-2}$ eV$^2$, you are not going to see oscillations in the trigonometric functions, *unless*  it is enhanced by a ***long*** *L/E* compensating for its smallness!

- How long? for the above $10^{-2}$ eV$^2$ you need to go to $L/E> 100$km/GeV. For reactors, *E*~3MeV, you get such *L/E*s for *L*>0.3km; for accelerators, *E*~ 1GeV, you need *L*>100km.

"Medium" refers to *L/E*s intermediate between these two cases. Including a summary table from the same reference:
[image]

Comment: I am having some probelm in understanding $\Delta m^2$. I was reading about different experiments like Double CHOOz, KAMLAND, Palo Verde and came across this term many times. I think it has something to do with the range but I do not know how.

Comment: [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation). It represents the difference of the masses squared of the various mass eigenstates of neutrinos!